# How do I dispatch the id in redux saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Just getting to know redux saga, how can I pass in my data in the dispatch? 
Currently my root saga looks like this:

```
function* getData(id){
  const data = yield fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+id)
  .then(response=>response.json())

  yield put({type:"RECEIVED_DATA",json:data})
}

export default function* rootSaga(){
  yield takeEvery("GET_DATA",getData)
}
```

How can I dispatch in an id in the getData generator?

[codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/7310qm92vj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `id` through the `action` object. Like this:

```
function* getData(action){  // fixed
  const id = action.id // we get the `id` from the `action` object

  const data = yield fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+id)
  .then(response=>response.json())

  yield put({type:"RECEIVED_DATA",json:data})
}

export default function* rootSaga(){
  yield takeEvery("GET_DATA",getData)
}
```

The is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ojlyzyq5oy